Secure Key Size in an extension field
For the Multiplicative Diffie Hellman, it's advised to use a Key Size of 2048 bits. This effectively translates to a Finite Field where the modulus is 2048 bits - i.e. $F_p$ where $p$ is 2048 bits.
Is it the same for an extension field also - i.e. is the discrete log problem hard in an extension field $F_{p^k}$ only if $p^k$ is 2048 bits?

The discrete logarithm is much easier on extension fields with small characteristic $p$ and such setups should be avoided. There are even
quasi-polynomial algorithms for this case, see for example the paper by Barbulescu et al here, where for $F_{p^n}$ the discrete logarithm problem can be solved with essentially
$$
O(n^{\log n})
$$
complexity where $n$ is the bitsize of the input.
See also this related question here.
Edit: The answer to the following question (thanks @kelalaka) is very comprehensive listing multiple attacks and availability of more attack vectors, for the case of $p=2.$

Little help; https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/91611/18298
